# Why don't my CSS media queries work appropriately

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to create a website which is responsive on mobile and desktop, but my media queries won't work (it's do nithing).

I put my link below if any body wants html and css.

my CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
.container{
    width: 30vw;
}
.show-onscreen{
    display: block;
}
.hide-onscreen{
    display: none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 900px){
    .container{
        width: 50vw ;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
    .container{
        width: 99vw ;
    }
}
```

and this is full code:
[full code](https://jsfiddle.net/AliBalouchi/auposL79/)

Comment: Please include the markup in your question as well. See [mcve] for more information. Also, please describe *how* your media queries don't work. Do things change, but not the way you want? Does nothing change at all when you resize? etc.

Comment: This `@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 900px)` doesn't make sense. Wasn't it supposed to be `@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px)`? Perhaps, this is the problem...

Comment: @LucasArbex i try what you say but it's not working yet

Comment: I've assumed that this was your problem because you didn't describe what you are trying to achieve. Please, be more specific on what you have already done to fix the problem, and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the below query might be the issue:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 900px){
    .container{
        width: 50vw ;
    }
}
```

here min-width is greater than max-width, hence it will never execute.

You can try below if that is your goal:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px){
    .container{
        width: 50vw ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 900px){
    .container{
        width: 50vw ;
    }
}
```

- `max-width: 700px` && `min-width: 900px` will never be true since width cannot be less than 700 and more that 900 on the same time.

I assume you meant to set the rules to be between 700 to 900

`@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 700px){`

Switch the width values in the media query

Answer (score 1):

To build and website mobile-first you should develop first for mobile and then other sizes.

You will need to use something like this:

Usage: for mobile (except smallest screens), tablet, laptop, desktop, bigscreen. Anyone over **480px**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 // content
}
```

Usage: for tablet, laptop, desktop, bigscreen. Anyone over **768px**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 // content
}
```

Usage: for laptop, desktop and bigscreen. Anyone over **992px**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
 // content
}
```

Usage: for desktop and bigscreen. Anyone over **1200px**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 // content
}
```

Usage: just for bigscreen over **1600px**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
 // content
}
```

To use this code you can develop without set media queries until you need to change some css property for bigger screens.

I suggest you to read this article: [A Hands-On Guide to Mobile-First Responsive Design](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/)

[image]